# How to type define a bound this

Tags: typescript, kurento

I'm using a [library](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-utils-js) with a [function](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-utils-js/blob/master/lib/WebRtcPeer.js#L180) that takes a `callback`, and then (frustratingly) calls `callback = (callback || noop).bind(this)`. In the `callback`, I need to grab `this`:

```
    kurento_utils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendonly(options, function (error: any) {
        if ( error ) {
            return on_error(error);
        }
        let webRTC_peer = this;  // kurento_utils binds 'this' to the callback
                       // ^^^^ error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. 

        webRTC_peer.generateOffer((error: string | undefined, offer: string) => {

...
```

TypeScript is (understandably) unhappy with this situation, at least when the `noImplicitThis` flag is enabled.

I have no idea how to properly type annotate `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `this` parameter to the function. This parameter will not be emitted to Javscript, and will be just for the benefit of the compiler so it can correctly type `this` witing the function:

```
 kurento_utils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendonly(options, function (this:WebRtcPeer, error: any) {
      let webRTC_peer = this; // this will be of type WebRtcPeer
 }
```

Or if you also control the `WebRtcPeerSendonly` you could specify that the function it takes as a parameter will have a certain `this` passed to it and type inference will work for `this` just as any other parameter:

```
class WebRtcPeer {
    WebRtcPeerSendonly(options: any, fn: (this: WebRtcPeer, error: any) => void) {

    }
}

new WebRtcPeer().WebRtcPeerSendonly({}, function(error){
    let webRTC_peer = this; // this will be of type WebRtcPeer
})
```

Comment: I'd read about adding an extra `this` parameter, but I must've missed that it isn't emitted to Javascript. Thanks for enlightening me!